# Eclipse searching for the wrong surefire dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-surefire-plugin

On building my workspace, my Java 6 Maven project is marked with an error (a Maven problem):

```
Could not calculate build plan: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire:pom:2.7.1 is not available in the local repository.
```

What strikes me as odd is that it is searching for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire while the true dependency is org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-plugin.

My effective pom is showing:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7.1</version>
<executions>
```

I'm using Eclipse Indigo with the m2eclipse plugin. And it compiles correctly when running any Maven goal. I tried cleaning the project, reimporting it, clearing the .metadata file.
Where does this behavior come from? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned dependency is the parent project for the maven-surefire-plugin and should usually not given directly only via the maven-surefire-plugin itself.

Furthermore `What strikes me as odd is that it is searching for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire while the true dependency is org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-plugin.` which is simply wrong, cause the correct groupId and artifactId for the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven.plugins%7Cmaven-surefire-plugin%7C2.7.2%7Cmaven-plugin) is:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.2</version>
  ...
</plugin>
```

It could be possible having problems while accessing maven central. Apart from the above you should update the maven-surefire-plugin cause the current up-to-date version is 2.15.